# Private Blockchain transactions throughput

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

I'm looking for a way to maximize the transactions throughput of my ethereum private blockchain.

I noticed that calling `eth.sendTransaction()` takes about 0.3 seconds to complete which is a considerable amount of time for me.

I limited the mining difficulty in the genesis file but this delay is even before the mining starts.

So is there a way to have faster transactions in ethereum?

Comment: as you know this all about the mining and the network difficulty, to increase your throughput use a private network with POA or fix the diff

Comment: But sendTransaction() returns before generating the block and mining it.